# Not supported for DML operations with JPA update query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hql

This has been asked once before but the solution did not solve the issue. I am creating a JUnit test:

```
 @Test
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    public void updateMaterialInventory() throws Exception{

        // Initialize the database
        materialRepository.saveAndFlush(material);

        long id =  material.getId();
        materialRepository.updateMaterialInventory(id,UPDATED_INVENTORY_COUNT);

        assertEquals(material.getInventory_count(), UPDATED_INVENTORY_COUNT, 0);
    }
```

The query the above test is calling is:

```
 @Query("UPDATE Material m SET m.inventory_count = ?2 WHERE m.id = ?1")
    void updateMaterialInventory(Long id,int newInventoryAmount);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.htd.domain.Material m SET m.inventory_count = ?2 WHERE m.id = ?1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.errorIfDML(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
    ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The `@Modifying` annotation must be placed on the `updateMaterialInventory` method, along to the `@Query` annotation, to let Spring-data know that the query is not a query used to select values, but to update values.

Comment: why I get "Executing an update/delete query" exception on update?

Comment: @Kenji
Add this:
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)

Comment: Add `@Transactional` to the service that's calling the repository. Add `@Modifying` to the query method in the Repository.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you should not use `@Transactional` annotation in the repository class. Find the below answer.

> Service Impl class

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
...
@Test
@Transactional
public void updateMaterialInventory() throws Exception{

    // Initialize the database
    materialRepository.saveAndFlush(material);

    long id =  material.getId();
    materialRepository.updateMaterialInventory(id,UPDATED_INVENTORY_COUNT);

    assertEquals(material.getInventory_count(), UPDATED_INVENTORY_COUNT, 0);
}
```

> Repository class

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
...

  @Modifying
  @Query("UPDATE Material m SET m.inventory_count = ?2 WHERE m.id = ?1")
  void updateMaterialInventory(Long id,int newInventoryAmount);
```

make sure to use the correct imports. hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(DELETE_INVOICE_BY_NUMBER)
public void deleteInvoiceByNumber(@Param("number") int number);
```

This worked for me, But without @Transactional in the repository class it give an error.

Comment: This did the trick but is there any explanation why the `@Transactional` has to be in the repository? If I place it outside on the calling method, I still get error...

Answer (score 2):

When you added the `@Modifying` and it's still not working then make sure your query is of type `void`, so nothing is returned.

Hibernate in its internals tries then to fetch the date which causes then that exception (not the update statement itselfs).