# Error Springboot query Not supported for DML operations

Tags: java, jquery, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to assign office for employees with same department. I'm gettin this error. What's the problem here ?

"org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update com.example.macademiaproject.model.Employee u set u.office = :office where u.department = :department]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update com.example.macademiaproject.model.Employee u set u.office = :office where u.department = :department]",

Query :

```
@Modifying
    @Query("update Employee u set u.office = :office where u.department = :department")
    List <Employee> assignOffice (@Param("office") String office,
                      @Param("department") String department);
```

ServiceImpl :

```
@Override
    public List<Employee> assignOffice(String department,String office) {
           List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.assignOffice(office,department);
           return employees;
       }
```

Controller :

```
 @GetMapping(path="/assign")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> assignOffice(@RequestParam("office")  String office,
                                                          @RequestParam("department") String department){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.assignOffice(office,department));

    }
```

Comment: hi i think it's helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47066289

Comment: I changed query to void. Now Implemantion method returns null. It work's without error but nothing changes at database. Maybe there is a problem with my methods

Answer (score 0):

@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)

can you try this annotation or you can take a look at this link.
[Spring Boot Data JPA - Modifying update query - Refresh persistence context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258857/spring-boot-data-jpa-modifying-update-query-refresh-persistence-context)